# After Exporting an SSL Cert from IIS, Does It Stay Active?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

Noob question: I'm moving a domain to a new server. When I export the SSL Cert from IIS, does it remain active on the host? I just want to make sure the export process doesn't remove the certificate from our site before I'm ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it stays active. Exporting just makes a copy. Make sure you export (or already have a copy of) the private key as well if you intend to use the cert on a new host.